# Does a vent register boot always has to be installed parallel to wall for a better air flow all around?

Tags: hvac, ducts

In my basement, I have a gas pipe (1" diameter) running between the joists. There is a reason why I have choose this cavity to run a supply line from where. But I am end up using a end boot register which would be perpendicular to the exterior wall. I have seen in my house in the upper living area,  builder used 90 degree vent register most of places and, few places the end boot register. In all case, the register vent boots is install parallel to any wall.

Would there be any problem in the air flow, if I run a supply through end vent boot which will be perpendicular to outer wall. The below is the picture I am trying to say. this vent will be just above the exterior door [image]

End boot register :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The air flow will be the same but the distribution of that air will be compromised. Supply vents up through the floor are usually aimed at the wall and air flows up the wall and into the room, the reason for them being installed parallel to the wall. It's also stands a better chance of not being obstructed by furniture in the room. A perpendicularly installed vent looses the "Wall effect" and also stands a good chance of being obstructed by furniture because it will stick out far.

Comment: Thanks Jack. If furniture is not a concern as the end boot is just above an exterior door. How the air will be compromised here ?

Comment: Does this vent supply air to the basement or first floor? the exterior door in the basement threw me.

Comment: its in basement.

Comment: @PAN  if it's blowing cold air down into the basement area, the air flow won't be compromised. If the vent register has directional guides, direct them away from the wall.

Comment: Thanks Jack! I am considering the hot air won't also compromised. since your specifically mentioned cold air.

Comment: @PAN Hot air won't b compromised either but you'd want to adjust the directional guides more downward since the hot air will rise.

Comment: @PAN  Just an after thought: is there  reason your extending that duct work all the way to the exterior wall?  Splitting the distance between the main trunk and the outside wall would reduce the duct work (resistance) and allow for better air flow into that room....  just a thought.

Comment: Good Point Jack Are you asking why not to put supply vent in the middle of space in the ceiling than running it all the way to exterior wall ? Actually I heard and seen that supply vent should be installed to exterior wall to stop cold draft coming from window in winter and,  another reason you mentioned due to furniture placement,. btw the total length of flex duct will be 13 feet.

Comment: @PAN I would  fix the windows with weather stripping. The furniture issue really only applies if the vent was coming through the floor  to cool/heat the first floor. Putting the supply vent in the middle just seems to make more sense IMHO.